# Does the Pipe in binding flags not represent an 'OR'

Tags: c#, reflection, bindingflags

I am currently debugging in the immediate window:

-

This returns 0 properties:

```
type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance)
```

This also returns 0 properties:

```
type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public)
```

But this returns both properties:

```
type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public)
```

And so does this:

```
type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)
```

I would have thought that if it was an `or` then if both the bottom return `true` then so should the top two.

Could someone explain to me how this works please?

Comment: No, `|` and `&` has dual purpose depending on the type of operands, it can either be logical OR (if booleans are involved) or bitwise OR (if non-boolean ordinal types are involved). The latter applies in this case. Either way, for logical OR, `||` would be the short-circuit type.

Comment: In other words, this is combining enum flags bitwise to create a mask, it's not a boolean expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see documentation of [GetProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetProperties_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_). You must specify visibility (Public/Private) and if it should be Static or Instance properties.